# Users and Google's cache get BAD redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I posted a link to an excellent article on javascript deletion issues here:

[Is the garbage collector called after window.location redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109085/2225842)

The link is:

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

And I can open that link just fine. It's a great article.

However, other users say it had viagra, etc. ads instead.

When I tried typing this into google:

```
cache:http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/
```

I got the very same thing they did - the page was retitled "canadian pharmacy viagra", and much of the page was chopped apart (you can tell where the text used to be)

It seems the link was previously hacked somehow.

Bill the Lizard deleted the post, which I agree with - the issue made it more about the link and less about the content.

My question is this:

How can I modify the link so that it can't redirect to the old/hacked page for some people?

I think I'm out of my league with this one. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, I sent a request to Google to have the old page removed from the cache. However, I'm not certain that will be a permanent fix.

The users that were finding the bad page weren't looking at Google's cache page - not that I know of. I just tried that to see if I could see what they did - and succeeded.

I would imagine they and the cache were being redirected - so even if the cache is fixed, it might still happen to someone. Is this right?

I've seen the same results in both Chrome and Firefox, on Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8.0.

Comment: Link seems to work fine for me. Not sure about the answer though :|

Comment: Did you try it with google's cache: ? It's still brings a hacked page for me. So I still can access both.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I went to the link directly. I think your best bet is https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663691?hl=en

Comment: I sent them a request. I'm just curious why some people found it so fast - it doesn't sound like it's only google's cache - it sounds like a redirect that they and cache took, but i didn't.

Comment: I'm not sure that this (https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/data-compression) would be related, but, given the use of certain optimization technologies like that, I could see where there might be some other caching involved.

Comment: I don't think it's a fail of Google. When I access the page directly, I get the pharmacy ads as well. The hackers might send out the bad page based on region settings or whatnot, maybe to disconcert the webmasters. Or not the site itself is infected, but one of the caches/proxies delivering it to certain users.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is an issue with Google's service, not a programming related problem.

Comment: You didn't read it all then - In response to comments, I said it wasn't Google' service - only that Google was falling for the same trap as users, enabling some of us to see both pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several reason reasons why only a subset of people might be seeing the cached/hacked version:

1. Perhaps an edge caching server like Akamai could be serving that cached page
2. Google's indexes could be slowly updating (since they have multiple indexes organized by region)
3. The ISP could have its own cache (however, I think this one is unlikely)
4. The engine supplying the ads on that page (or another plugin) could be corrupt where it ends up replacing the content or downloading additional content.

The only way to tell would be to look at the Chrome Debugger. Your best bet for now is to ask google to remove the cached page [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663691?hl=en)

Comment: In this case there's nothing I can do to fix the problem, but I still think it's important to have answers to this - for people who have this happen to their site. Maybe someone in that situation can improve the question and add example code, etc.

Comment: I don't see what Chrome Debugger would help here. The ads are placed directly in the HTML markup (while upholding the original structure, which I find quite interesting), a simple `View Source` will be enough.

Comment: Well, if the ads are static then yes. I didn't get a chance to investigate that. I figured that if the content was dynamically loaded, it could be possible to track the source via the Network Panel in the Chrome debugger.